# Google Custom Search Engine is breaking my other javascript

Tags: javascript, html, google-custom-search

For some reason when I add Google Custom Search Engine to my website it breaks all my other javascript.

Here is my GCSE code:

```
<div class="search">
    <script>
        (function() {
             var cx = '001006982041148688432:o4szcri0t6k';
             var gcse = document.createElement('script');
             gcse.type = 'text/javascript';
             gcse.async = true;
             gcse.src = (document.location.protocol == 'https:' ? 'https:' : 'http:') +
                 '//www.google.com/cse/cse.js?cx=' + cx;
             var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
             s.parentNode.insertBefore(gcse, s);
         })();
    </script>
    <gcse:search></gcse:search>
</div>
```

Here is an example of code (a basic image preload script) it breaks:

```
<div class="hidden">
    <script type="text/javascript">
        <!--//--><![CDATA[//><!--
            var images = new Array()
            function preload() {
                for (i = 0; i < preload.arguments.length; i++) {
                    images[i] = new Image()
                    images[i].src = preload.arguments[i]
                }
            }
            preload(
                "./pictures/GreenGamingPrev.png",
                "./pictures/SleekPhotographyPrev.png",
                "./pictures/MetalBandPrev.png"
                "./pictures/FamilyRestaurantPrev.png"
            )
        //--><!]]>
    </script>
</div>
```

Any reason why it would be doing this? Is this a know issue or am I doing something wrong?

edit: Here is my website if that is more useful. http://www.eclipsetemplates.com

Comment: Can you check your console for errors and put it here?

Comment: 1 warning: Use of getUserData() or setUserData() is deprecated. Use WeakMap or element.dataset instead. requestNotifier.js:64

Comment: Check If you are using updated code for Google custom search.
Your console giving hints regarding it